# How to show alert dialog box in adapter class without click?

Tags: android

I am trying to show alert dialog box in adapter class without click on any item. when dialog box will appear so it will get the value from first row of adapter class and the value will be show in dialog box and when i click on button in dialog box then next activity will call.

Alert Dialog box will be show before this line `Utility.makecall(mContext, mData.get(position).getPhone(),SharedPref.Getsimetype(SharedPref.SIMTYPE,""));`and this line execute when i click on button in dialog box.

```
public class Contactadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Contactadapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Callcontactsmodel> mData;
private Callcontactfragment callcontactfragment;

public Contactadapter(Context mContext, Callcontactfragment callcontactfragment) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = new ArrayList<>();
    this.callcontactfragment = callcontactfragment;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_contacts, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    try {
        holder.tv_numbers.setText(mData.get(position).getPhone() == null ? "" : mData.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.tv_time.setText(mData.get(position).getName() == null ? "" : mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_type.setText(mData.get(position).getContact_type().getName() == null ? "" : mData.get(position).getContact_type().getName());
        if (0 == position && callcontactfragment.auto_call){
            callcontactfragment.setCallcontactid(mData.get(position).getId().toString());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Utility.makecall(mContext, mData.get(position).getPhone(),SharedPref.Getsimetype(SharedPref.SIMTYPE,""));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public void setItems(List<Callcontactsmodel> items) {
    mData = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItems(List<Callcontactsmodel> items) {
    mData.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearitem() {
    mData.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.tv_time)
    AppCompatTextView tv_time;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_type)
    AppCompatTextView tv_type;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_numbers)
    AppCompatTextView tv_numbers;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        tv_numbers.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                callcontactfragment.setCallcontactid(mData.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId().toString());
                Utility.makecall(mContext, mData.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPhone(),SharedPref.Getsimetype(SharedPref.SIMTYPE,""));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work or not but try it
in your onBindViewHolder check the position that

```
 if(position == 0){
     MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(mContext)
        .setTitle("Your title")
        .setMessage("pass your first row data as in string form")
        // add buttons positive or negative
        .create()
        .show()
 }
```

Comment: it's showing dialog box but i want to show data of first row in alert dialog box

Comment: then store your first row data in some variable and display it into the set message() as a string